# Bitcoin Core not showing content of address

Tags: bitcoin-core

Bitcoin core newbie here.
I have an old wallet  backed up here, and upon download of the latest blockchain info, importing the wallet, my balance is empty.

Now I do have 3 transactions which I made in 2018, including one on which I transferred all my remaining assets. One of these addresse, upon blockchain explorer verification, indeed contains my asset.

How can I access it via bitcoin core? The wallet was originaly created within Bitcoin Core.
When getting the private key to the address holding my asset, and importing the priv key into an alternative wallet such as electrum, I can't see the public address holding my assets and not access them either.

Can someone tell me how I can access the content of the public access bound to my private key please?

I spent hours on this already...

cheers

Answer (score 1):

> **download of the latest blockchain info, importing the wallet,**

If you did it in that order you probably need to [rescan](https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.21.0/rpc/wallet/rescanblockchain/) using the console or command line options.

> rescanblockchain ( start_height stop_height )
>
> Rescan the local blockchain for wallet related transactions. Note: Use
> "getwalletinfo" to query the scanning progress.
>
> Arguments:
>
> 1. start_height    (numeric, optional, default=0) block height where the rescan should start
> 2. stop_height     (numeric, optional) the last block height that should be scanned. If none is provided it will rescan up to the tip at
>    return time of this call.

Comment: Thanks for that! so sorry for the late response. How woud I go about finding the block the transaction is located in ? I have a transaction ID but that's it... sorry for being a newbie

Comment: @SpadeJohnsson, I don't know how to do that with Bitcoin-core but some blockchain explorers will tell you the block number (block height) of the block that contains a transaction with a specified transaction ID. For example https://blockchair.com/bitcoin/transaction/871477b57c61ff4d002552f8b104a11b3d21d51e7f459c17485738bb154a7aeb says "Block id 
704,0072"

Comment: Ok tanks a lot mate, I'll dig into this throughout the week-end!